# Rescale videos to square screen

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a square screen amv format video player which is 1 inch by 1 inch.
I would like to rescale videos that have different aspect ratios to fit the screen. I am using ffmpeg.

My goal is to have the best quality video possible. I need to downscale all videos to a square screen about 256x256 resolution. Right now, widescreen videos are so squished that the quality is bad and I can't read any text.

I don't mind cropping some of the sides of the video so that the quality is better.

Please give me some ideas on how to use the ffmpeg scale filter to downscale videos to fit a square screen with the best possible quality.

Here is my current command:

-c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf "scale=296:256:force_original_aspect_ratio=decreas e,crop=256:in_h:20:0" -vstrict -1 -r 25 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -block_size 882

This works well and it crops some of the side of the widescreen videos, but I think it can be better.

Thanks!!

Comment: "best" quality is rather subjective. Anything with text is likely to fail, as 256x256 is a tiny screen. Can you edit your post to tell us what you want your output to be? I mean, I'd just crop the sides until I had a square and then shrink, but that won't work for all folks.